# Access Cardboard VR Setting from Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, settings, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

While in Cardboard VR-Mode you can use a cogwheel icon in the top-right-corner.
This button access the VR Settings.

I want to access it directly inside of Unity3D.
I cant find any api making that available or mention it.

please help :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

**Assuming you mean either the settings button or the Cardboard back button, it seems you can customize the one via listening for KeyCode.Escape, but that the other one is fixed.**

Source:

> You can customize the behaviour of the Cardboard back button by listening for Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)), but the Settings button is not override-able.

https://forum.unity.com/threads/accessing-cardboard-back-and-configure-buttons.461975/